# Recursive querying of hierarchical data using CTE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, hierarchy, common-table-expression

I have two tables

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Folder](
  [FolderID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [FolderName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
  [ParentFolderID] [int] NULL
)
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FolderSubscription](
  [UserID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [FolderID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [IncludeSubfolders] [bit] NOT NULL
)
```

The `[IncludeSubfolders]` field means that if a user has subscribed subfolders also.

#### My goal is to get to know if a user has subscribed to a particular folder.

I tried the following recursive query. but no luck

```
DECLARE @FolderID INT=2,
        @UserID INT= 1
WITH SubFolderS_CTE (FolderID,ParentFolderID,FolderSubscription)
AS
(
        SELECT 
            Folder.FolderID,
            Folder.ParentFolderID,
            DMSsubscription.IncludeSubfolders
        FROM 
            FolderSubscription
        INNER JOIN 
            Folder
        ON 
            Folder.FolderID = FolderSubscription.FolderID
        WHERE 
            FolderSubscription.FolderID = @FolderID AND FolderSubscription.UserID = @UserID

        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            folder.FolderID,
            folder.ParentFolderID
            ,sub.IncludeSubfolders
        FROM
            FolderSubscription sub
        INNER JOIN
                Folder folder
        ON   folder.FolderID = sub.FolderID
        INNER JOIN
            SubFolderS_CTE
        ON folder.FolderID = SubFolderS_CTE.ParentFolderID
)
SELECT * FROM SubFolderS_CTE
```

Data..

```
FolderID |  FolderName |  ParentFolderID
----------------------------------------
   1     |     Po      |     NULL       
   2     |   Tigress   |      1         
   3     |    Mantis   |      2
```

Subscription..

```
 UserID  |   FolderID  |  IncludeChildren
----------------------------------------
   1     |     2       |      1
```

Comment: +1 on effort and providing *all* necessary data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't or don't like to use a `hierarchyid` as proposed by @CResults, following might get you started using plain `CTE's`.

```
DECLARE @IsSubscribedToFolderID INT = 2
DECLARE @UserID INT = 1

/* Test Data */
;WITH Folder (FolderID, FolderName, ParentFolderID) AS (
    SELECT  1, 'Po', NULL
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'Tigress', 1
    UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'Mantis', 2
)
, FolderSubscription (UserID, FolderID, IncludeChildren) AS (
    SELECT  1, 2, 1
)
/* Actual Query */
, q AS (
    SELECT  f.FolderID
            , [MasterFolderID] = f.FolderID
    FROM    Folder f
            INNER JOIN FolderSubscription fs ON fs.FolderID = f.FolderID
    WHERE   fs.UserID = @UserID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  f.FolderID
            , q.MasterFolderID
    FROM    q
            INNER JOIN Folder f ON f.ParentFolderID = q.FolderID
            INNER JOIN FolderSubscription fs ON fs.FolderID = q.MasterFolderID AND fs.IncludeChildren = 1)
SELECT  q.*
FROM    q
        INNER JOIN Folder f ON f.FolderID = q.FolderID
WHERE   q.FolderID = @IsSubscribedToFolderID
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the `hierarchyid` datatype. It makes queries such as this so much easier. Looking to see if one folder is the descendent of another is then just a where clause rather than lots of recursion

Unfortunately though its a SQL2008+ only option which from your tags may stop you from using it

Comment: Thanks it helps..i use sql server 2008